# Merging two dataclasses

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, python-dataclasses

Let A be a dataclass that contains at least the attributes in the dataclass  B.

In python, is there a simple way to merge an instance of B and an instance of A in the same way two dictionaries are merged with the `|` operator as in the example below?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, replace

@dataclass
class A:
    x: int 
    y: int 

@dataclass
class B:
    x: int 

a=A(x=2,y=6)
b=B(x=4)
```

The current simplest solutions i found were:

1. To convert both instances to dictionaries, do the merge into a single dictionary, then convert back to dataclass as in the code below:

```
c_dict : dict = asdict(a) | asdict(b)
c_1=A(**c_dict)
```

2. To use the replace function and asdict conversion  as in the code below:

```
c_2=replace(a,**asdict(b))
```

Is this the simplest way? For instance trying `a|b` fails as an 'unsupported operand'.

Comment: no, no there isn't.

Comment: send message to authors of python and maybe they add `a|b` in next version ;)

Comment: This code does not do anything useful. What is the result you expect?

Comment: `asdict(b) | asdict(a)` would simply result in a copy of `asdict(a)` since all keys of `asdict(b)` are overwritten. As it is, the idea is entirely pointless.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks for the comment! I edited the question to make it closer to the use case i was thinking of. Now there are two types of dataclasses included in each other. This comes from the realization that a dataclass is a type of extension of dictionary where all keys specified in the class will necessarily exist once constructed (which i did not know when first formulating my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is nothing built-in that will support the `a | b` behavior, you can implement on your own a mixin class with the `__or__` method defined:

```
@dataclass
class Unionable:
    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(**asdict(self) | asdict(other))
```

so that:

```
@dataclass
class A(Unionable):
    x: int
    y: int

@dataclass
class B(Unionable):
    x: int

a = A(x=2, y=6)
b = B(x=4)
print(a | b)
```

outputs:

```
A(x=4, y=6)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/rEDBzN

Answer (score 0):

Without using `asdict` function, you can use `__dict__` of the dataclass and use `|`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    field1: int
    field2: int

a = A(1, 2)
a2 = A(3, 4)

res = A(**a.__dict__ | a2.__dict__)
```